# Is there a way to bookmark/favourite a form search?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, bookmarks

Of course if the search is via GET it's easy to bookmark, but what if the search is via POST ? Can I bookmark it so I don't need to type in the search paramaters?

Comment: @pablobart the answer here is much better than any over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [Imacros](http://imacros.net/overview) can serve your needs.  There are extensions for both Firefox and Chrome available.

I'm sure there are plenty others as well.  Try searching for `automate` or `automation` at each of the browsers' extension/plugin sites.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox you can right click the search and add a Keywoard for the search. Then just type your keyword and search parameter like so:

google superuser

I believe there's a similar option for Chrome and IE.